# Use same ID for popover

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have multiple buttons on my website and I want them all to use the same popover ID. The problem is, the only popover that actually works is for the button at the top of the page.

If I click any other button (with the exact same settings and popover ID), it won't open. Only the top one opens.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: then have the `popover` select the element by class, and have the classes different, that way you can have all the IDs the same.

Comment: Never use duplicate IDs in the same DOM. While retrieving, it gives you only 1 node. So, use classnames instead

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique.

Comment: Why would you want to have same ID for all buttons? As what @karthikr and KevinM1 said ID should be unique. If you want all buttons to show the same popover you should use a same CSS class for all buttons and use the class as selector to activate the popover.

Comment: I thinks he's talking about using the same **target** ID. That is, having an unique popover with `id="something"` and targeting it with many buttons, there's only a `#something` element.

Comment: Thanks guys, I just used the class I was using for the link. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using IDs, I had to use the class.